# MS Access Forms: Add table/gridview

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, ms-access-2010, sharepoint-2007

I'm designing an Access 2010 form (my first time) and I need to recreate a form that previously existed and was created with InfoPath. The reason for the switch is because the date was moved from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2007 and InfoPath doesn't provide enough support to create the form in the same way as the previous one with SharePoint 2007.

Back to Access now, I was wondering how to create an HTML-table like structure like in image below:

[image: Gridview example]

I don't seem to find an option to add a table like this but under the `Arrange` tab I do find options for adding a new row, merge/split cells, etc... Allthough they are disabled, they're still there...

So how can I add this to a form using Access 2010?

If there are still questions or remarks please don't hesitate to ask, I'd be happy to give you more information I might have forgotten.

EDIT 1: This form will only be used to enter date into a list, no more, no less.

Comment: This seems like a much easier task using ASP for the gridview... Jussayin'...

Comment: I know, but my supervisor prefers I use a technology known within the company -_-

Answer (score 0):

I've actually found a [neat, long, detailed explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910449/how-to-display-record-data-in-a-table-in-ms-access-form)

**TL;DR:**

Use a continues form - it repeats its own elements in a way that can easily mimic a table. You can drop pictures, even buttons, check boxes and even combo boxes. They will all repeat as a grid for you.

Comment: Thank a lot! This could come in handy for the future but right now I don't need a repeating table. I just want to be able to create something just like in the example image. And afterwards add textboxes for databinding to be able to insert 1 new record in a table. Please tell me where you got confused so I can edit the question.

Comment: @Gravinco This is not for repeating the table, You repeat elements - like, textboxes, or values. A lot of textboxes put next to each other in columns & rows will look like a table. :)